# How to persist an entity in hibernate with composite key of which one is primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
1. I have two table EMPLOYEE and SKILL as below.
2. Each employee has a set of skills.

create table Employee(emp_id int not null, name varchar(255) not null,
primary key (emp_id)
);

create table SKILL(emp_id int not null, skill_id int not null, skill_name varchar(255) not null,
primary key (emp_id, skill_id),
foreign key (emp_id) references Employee
);

1. how the entity mapping should look like.?
2. and how to persist an employee along with a set of skills in cascade.?
```

[Employee entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ytSm.png)

[Skill Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoaX7.png)

[composite key SkillId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJMHD.png)

[spring boot runner image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTc5H.png)

I get error "NULL not allowed for column "EMP_ID"; SQL statement:". I tried lot of things but unfortunately could not achieve persisting of Employee with cascade of Skill

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-3.0.10.jar:3.0.10]
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:269) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ...
    at com.example.springjpah2.repository.EmployeeRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.create(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    ...
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ...
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "EMP_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into skill (skill_name, emp_id, skill_id) values (?, ?, ?) [23502-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:508) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

After the above error I added,@MapsId(value="empId) in Skill entity, then I get a different error
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
      @MapsId(value = "empId")
      private Employee employee;

at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.10.jar:3.0.10]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.example.springjpah2.entity.Skill.employee]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:320) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
```